# ASP.NET MasterPage usage for authorization purposes

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I am using master pages for authorization. I have three different user types: Readers, Authors and Admins.

I have a `Main.Master` which has the fundamental things of my pages. Then I have,

1. Reader.Master
2. Author.Master
3. Admin.Master

These inherited from the `Main.Master`. I am checking if the user really logged in (`Session` is not null) and if the `UserType` is true in `Reader.Master`, `Author.Master`, `Admin.Master`s `Page_Init()` functions.

**First question:** Is that a good practice? Please consider that I have zero experience of using other ASP.NET built-in stuff for user management, authorization etc..

**Second question:** There are some pages like `ForgotPassword.aspx` which all `UserType`s should access the same page. In my structure, I need to create three different pages inherited from three different Master's. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

***Second question:** There are some pages like ForgotPassword.aspx which all UserTypes should access the same page. In my structure, I need to create three different pages inherited from three different Master's. How to solve this issue?*

Create `User.Master` and `Guest.Master` with same way and you will have masters for all kind of users.
User.Master will check only if user is logged in.

Answer (score 1):

To your **first question**: I use it similar. I'm not sure if it is a good solution but it works for me.

**Second question**: You can define `ContentPlaceHolder` in your master pages.

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MyId" runat="server" />
```

In your aspx site you define for each `ContentPlaceHolder` one `Content` container.

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PageContent" runat="server">
    <!-- content for this area -->
</asp:Content>
```

If you define in your three user type master pages `ContentPlaceHolder` with the same `ID` you can use in a page like Forgot.aspx the same content for each master page.

Answer (score 1):

well, authentication in master pages is acceptable, if not the best practice. I have seen many books that start with these kind of tutorial. however you may face some issues when your website scales, also handling authentication related data in other than pages like in haldlers or global.asax can be a pain.

However this kind of authentication will be OK when the scope of website is limited and you doesn't require advanced function.

regarding you 2nd question then yes what you are getting is the side effect of the method being used. what you can do is create only one page using any of three masterpages. in that master page where you are checking for authentication, there you get the name of the page, and if the page name is same as forgot.aspx or what ever just ignore get out of the normal process.

eg

```
if (System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.PhysicalPath).ToLower() == "forgot.aspx")
{

}
else
{
    doauthentication();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just make it as a normal webform page without master page, users can't log in if they forgot password, you only need to show them a normal page like the login page